# I am trying to populate a Tkinter grid from a JSON and limit the number of rows to 5, so when it reaches the fifth it'd continue into another column

Tags: python, json, tkinter, grid, auto

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:
[image: expected Tkinter grid]

But instead, what I am getting is this:
[image: reality Tkinter grid]

This is the structure:
The file that's getting the JSON data, called bitmex.py

```
import requests

def get_contracts():
    response_object = requests.get('https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/instrument/active')

    contracts = []

    for contract in response_object.json():
        contracts.append(contract['symbol'])
    
    return contracts

print(get_contracts())
```

And this is the main.py that is populating the data into a Grid:

```
import tkinter as tk
from bitmex import get_contracts
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bitmex_contracts = get_contracts()
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Bitmex Contracts")

    x = 0
    y = 0

    for contract in bitmex_contracts:
       label_widget = tk.Label(root, text=contract, borderwidth=1, relief=tk.SOLID, width=13).grid(row=x, column=y, sticky='ew')

       if x >= 4:
              y += 1
              x = 0      
    else:
        x += 1

    root.geometry('800x600')
    root.mainloop()
```

As you'll see the problem I am facing is that the data is getting one underneath each other but not on a grid but superimposed instead.
The version of Python I am using is v.3.9.7 and
Tkinter v.8.6

Comment: column is on the x axis and row is on the y axis

Comment: Exactly, that's right. But the data is not getting populated on any of them

Comment: is that `else` under the `for` loop? shouldn't it be with the `if` statement?

Comment: Well, this happened when I pasted the code, but actually the else is inside the if statement. The "for", the "if", and the "else" are the three on the same indentation line.

Comment: well, they shouldn't be, that `if` and `else` should be inside the `for` loop

Comment: Thank you so much Matiis! It was just an indentation issue. After I placed them both inside the for loop, it started to work as expected.